# Failed at the npm start script

Tags: npm, build, scripting, node-sass

Trying to run my application, getting the problem, complete log is placed below.

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   '/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.3/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.3/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.13
3 info using node@v14.17.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle lk_wur@1.0.0~prestart: lk_wur@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle lk_wur@1.0.0~start: lk_wur@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle lk_wur@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle lk_wur@1.0.0~start: PATH: /Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/user/Documents/projects/app/node_modules/.bin:/Users/user/.pyenv/shims:/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.3/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin:/Users/user/Documents/projects/app/node_modules/.bin
9 verbose lifecycle lk_wur@1.0.0~start: CWD: /Users/user/Documents/projects/app
10 silly lifecycle lk_wur@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'npm-run-all -p sass:watch start-cra' ]
11 silly lifecycle lk_wur@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle lk_wur@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: lk_wur@1.0.0 start: `npm-run-all -p sass:watch start-cra`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:375:28)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:375:28)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1055:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
14 verbose pkgid lk_wur@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd /Users/user/Documents/projects/app
16 verbose Darwin 22.6.0
17 verbose argv "/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.3/bin/node" "/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.3/bin/npm" "start"
18 verbose node v14.17.3
19 verbose npm  v6.14.13
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error lk_wur@1.0.0 start: `npm-run-all -p sass:watch start-cra`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the lk_wur@1.0.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

This is from package.json

```
"engines": {
    "node": ">=12",
    "yarn": "1.x"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "analyze": "yarn build && source-map-explorer 'build/static/js/*.js'",
    "build": "yarn sass:build && react-app-rewired build",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "format": "prettier --write '**/*.{ts,tsx,json,scss,md,html,yml,yaml}'",
    "format-check": "prettier --check '**/*.{ts,tsx,json,scss,md,html,yml,yaml}'",
    "extract-translations": "i18next-scanner",
    "sass:build": "node-sass --js --rewrite-urls=all --include-path=node_modules src/app/styles/main.scss src/app/styles/main.css",
    "sass:watch": "yarn sass:build && nodemon --ext sass --exec 'yarn sass:build'",
    "lint": "node ./node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js 'src/**/*.{js,ts,tsx}'",
    "start": "npm-run-all -p sass:watch start-cra",
    "start-cra": "cross-env PORT=9999 react-scripts start",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js",
    "lint:fix": "eslint src/**/*.js --fix",
    "prettier": "prettier --write src/**/*.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "11.2.5",
    "@types/classnames": "2.2.11",
    "@types/jest": "26.0.20",
    "@types/node": "14.14.28",
    "@types/nprogress": "0.2.0",
    "@types/react": "17.0.2",
    "@types/react-custom-scrollbars": "4.0.10",
    "@types/react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "@types/react-onclickoutside": "6.7.4",
    "@types/react-redux": "7.1.16",
    "@types/react-responsive": "8.0.2",
    "@types/react-router": "5.1.18",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "5.3.2",
    "@types/react-slick": "0.23.8",
    "@types/redux-auth-wrapper": "2.0.9",
    "cross-env": "7.0.3",
    "eslint": "7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.5.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "6.0.0",
    "eslint-loader": "4.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "5.10.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.25.4",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "3.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.29.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4.3.0",
    "husky": "4.3.8",
    "i18next-scanner": "3.0.0",
    "i18next-scanner-typescript": "1.0.6",
    "less": "4.1.1",
    "lint-staged": "10.5.4",
    "nodemon": "2.0.7",
    "npm-run-all": "4.1.5",
    "prettier": "2.6.0",
    "react-device-detect": "1.17.0",
    "react-input-mask": "2.0.4",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-toggle-switch": "3.0.4",
    "sass": "1.49.9",
    "source-map-explorer": "2.5.2",
    "typescript": "4.1.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@ant-design/icons": "4.7.0",
    "@babel/core": "7.17.8",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "7.17.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-development": "7.16.7",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-self": "7.16.7",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-source": "7.16.7",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-pure-annotations": "7.16.7",
    "@draft-js-plugins/counter": "4.1.1",
    "@draft-js-plugins/editor": "4.1.2",
    "@draft-js-plugins/linkify": "4.2.0",
    "@draft-js-plugins/static-toolbar": "4.1.2",
    "@loadable/component": "5.15.3",
    "@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin": "0.5.4",
    "@svgr/webpack": "5.5.0",
    "@toast-ui/react-image-editor": "3.15.2",
    "@types/react-copy-to-clipboard": "5.0.2",
    "@types/react-input-mask": "1.2.4",
    "@types/react-table": "7.7.10",
    "@types/reactstrap": "8.7.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.33.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.33.0",
    "antd": "4.24.12",
    "axios": "0.21.1",
    "babel-eslint": "10.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "26.6.3",
    "babel-loader": "8.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-named-asset-import": "0.3.8",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "10.0.1",
    "bfj": "7.0.2",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.3.0",
    "classnames": "2.2.6",
    "connected-react-router": "6.8.0",
    "css-loader": "4.3.0",
    "css-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "1.0.0",
    "dotenv": "8.2.0",
    "dotenv-expand": "5.1.0",
    "draft-js": "0.11.7",
    "draft-js-emoji-mart-plugin": "1.0.1",
    "draft-js-export-html": "1.4.1",
    "draft-js-focus-plugin": "3.0.1",
    "emoji-mart": "3.0.1",
    "es5-ext": "0.10.53",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "2.6.0",
    "history": "4.10.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "4.5.0",
    "i18next": "19.8.7",
    "i18next-xhr-backend": "3.2.2",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "3.0.0",
    "jest": "26.6.0",
    "jest-circus": "26.6.0",
    "jest-resolve": "26.6.0",
    "jest-watch-typeahead": "0.6.1",
    "localforage": "1.9.0",
    "lodash": "4.17.21",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "0.11.3",
    "node-sass": "5.0.0",
    "nprogress": "0.2.0",
    "oaf-react-router": "2.1.1",
    "pnp-webpack-plugin": "1.6.4",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "4.2.1",
    "postcss-loader": "3.0.0",
    "postcss-normalize": "8.0.1",
    "postcss-preset-env": "6.7.0",
    "postcss-safe-parser": "5.0.2",
    "prompts": "2.4.0",
    "rc-drawer": "0.4",
    "rc-time-picker": "3.7.3",
    "rc-util": "5.14.0",
    "react": "16.14.0",
    "react-app-polyfill": "2.0.0",
    "react-app-rewired": "2.2.1",
    "react-copy-to-clipboard": "5.0.4",
    "react-custom-scrollbars": "4.2.1",
    "react-day-picker": "7.4.10",
    "react-dev-utils": "11.0.4",
    "react-dom": "16.14.0",
    "react-i18next": "11.8.6",
    "react-image": "4.0.3",
    "react-images": "1.0.0",
    "react-infinite-scroll-component": "6.1.0",
    "react-infinite-scroller": "1.2.5",
    "react-intl": "5.24.7",
    "react-notifications": "1.7.3",
    "react-onclickoutside": "6.12.1",
    "react-outside-click-handler": "1.3.0",
    "react-placeholder": "4.1.0",
    "react-promise-tracker": "2.1.0",
    "react-redux": "7.2.2",
    "react-refresh": "0.11.0",
    "react-responsive": "8.2.0",
    "react-router": "5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "5.2.0",
    "react-select": "4.3.1",
    "react-simple-timefield": "3.2.5",
    "react-slick": "0.28.1",
    "react-sortable-hoc": "2.0.0",
    "react-table": "7.7.0",
    "react-table-sticky": "1.1.3",
    "react-toastify": "7.0.4",
    "reactstrap": "8.10.1",
    "recharts": "2.1.9",
    "redux": "4.0.5",
    "redux-auth-wrapper": "3.0.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "2.13.8",
    "redux-immutable-state-invariant": "2.1.0",
    "redux-logger": "3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "6.0.0",
    "redux-saga": "1.1.3",
    "reselect": "4.0.0",
    "resolve": "1.18.1",
    "sass-loader": "10.2.1",
    "slick-carousel": "1.8.1",
    "style-loader": "1.3.0",
    "styled-components": "5.3.6",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "4.2.3",
    "typesafe-actions": "5.1.0",
    "webpack": "4.44.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.11.1",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "2.2.0",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "5.1.4"
  },
```

What i've already done:
Switched node and python versions;
Cleared npm cache
Tried to install packages from package-lock.json running 'npm ci'

I assume this is a problem with node-sass package, got 5.0.0 version